# Perform test, get result from another column for the same row

Tags: r

I'm creating a function but i need some help with best practices.

```
    Active.Test <- function(date) {
  date <- rep(date,length(df$Start.Date))
  active <- rep(0,length(df$Start.Date))


  active[date > df$Start.Date & date < df$End.Date] <- 1
  active[df$Start.Date == df$End.Date  ] <- df$Active.Time
  return (active)
}
```

I basically want to check if a date (which is passed to the function) is between the start and end date in my data frame. If it is, assign a 1. If the start and end dates are equal, get the result from the same row in Active.Time column. Everything else has a default value of 0.

This returns an error as it's retrieving a vector which is of a different size for the second test.

I can re-write the above as:

```
    Active.Test <- function(date) {
  date <- rep(date,length(df$Start.Date))
  active <- rep(0,length(df$Start.Date))


  active[date > df$Start.Date & date < df$End.Date] <- 1
  active[df$Start.Date == df$End.Date] <- df$Active.Time[df$Start.Date == df$End.Date]
  return (active)
}
```

This will then get the correct element from the Active.Time column but this doesn't seem to be an elegant way to write this. I'm also guessing it's slower as i'm performing the same check twice as many times.

Could you please help me re-write this using best practices?

EDIT: Here's some code to get a few rows of data and then test use the function by checking to see if the start and end dates encompass 25/05/2016.

```
#Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(End.Date = as.Date(c("1/05/2016","28/05/2016", "25/05/2016"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), Start.Date = as.Date(c("20/04/2016 11:00","20/05/2016 23:00", "25/05/2016 10:00"), format = "%d/%m/%Y" ), Active.Time = as.numeric(c(0.5,0.4,0.8)))

#Test the function
df$new <- Active.Test(as.Date("25/05/2016", format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide a minimal dataset folks can work with right-away.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Added some data.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Using the data.table approach
library(data.table)

# Make data table instead of data.frame (you can also do as.data.table(df) to get a data.table)
my_dt <- data.table(Start.Date=as.Date(c("20/04/2016 11:00","20/05/2016 23:00", "25/05/2016 10:00"), format = "%d/%m/%Y" ), 
                    End.Date=as.Date(c("1/05/2016","28/05/2016", "25/05/2016"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
                    Active.Time = as.numeric(c(0.5,0.4,0.8))
                   )
setkey(my_dt)

# Sample date to test
datte <- as.Date("25/05/2016", format = "%d/%m/%Y")

# Create function with conditions and result to return
Active.Test <- function(datte, Start.Date, End.Date, Active.Time) {

  if(datte > Start.Date & datte < End.Date){
    return(1)
    }
  else if(Start.Date==End.Date){
    return(Active.Time)
    }
  else{return(0)}

  }

# Test function
my_dt[, res:=Active.Test(datte, Start.Date, End.Date, Active.Time), by=1:nrow(my_dt)]
```

See [data.table vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/package/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) for more on `data.table`. Also, in your function above, note the warning you get when you run `df$new <- Active.Test(as.Date("25/05/2016", format = "%d/%m/%Y"))`!

Comment: I'm trying to avoid embedded if functions as my number of conditions could grow.

Comment: All conditions have to be specified somewhere, no escaping that. A better way to implement the solution above would be to put all the conditions in a function similar to the one you had earlier. The function can then be (a) passed to a data.table in the fashion shown in the edited answer or (b) looped over rows of a dataframe/matrix with `apply(..., MARGIN=1)`. Both options, like the one in the old answer do not `rep` the input arguments. See the data.table vignette for why a data.table solution would be "better practice" : specifically, the `:=` operator and keys.